# ASP.NET MVC Select list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, select

When the user clicks edit button , User full profile information is displayed in textbox , user can make changes in it.. Problem is : When the user register , user selects a option from a list of value like below..

(i.e)

```
<select id="security_question" name="security_question">
   <option value="choosequestion" style="font-style:italic;"> Choose a question ... </option>
   <option value="What was your first phone number?">What was your first phone number?</option>
   <option value="What is your vehicle registration number?">What is your vehicle registration number?</option>
</select>
```

When user pressed edit button after logged in , i have to show this select list and User selected value( which is selected when user registers ) should be selected in this list... How to do this ????

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Good morning assuming your view is Strongly-Typed to a viewmodel, let's say an entity called "UserAccount" with an attribute called "SecretQuestion", you could setup this select box using the Html helper "DropdownListFor".  You simply set the model property that it is bound to and MVC should handle the rest.